# I need to setup a Magento Site, with two seperate websites, the same products but different prices/skus

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I need to setup a Magento Site, with two seperate websites, the same products but different prices/skus.

Right now I added in two custom attribute fields for each product with the other company sku/price. I have a flag that chooses which product sku/price to show.

Is this feasible with Magento or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is designed so that each product has only 1 SKU. They do this so that you can use Magento to manage stock on a SKU basis. If stock is not of concern to you, then your way will work fine. However, the correct way to do this would be to have two different products.

If the two products are identical, but you just want to determine which store they came from, there are other ways to do what you are trying to do.

I'd say you're doing it wrong, but that's really just my opinion. You can go about it whichever way you choose!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a product a price for each website. Yes, SKU are global but as Mike stated, if you want to keep track of your stock you should follow magento logic on this.
Add your product then set a different price for each of your website.
If the product is sold either way stock will be changed accordingly and you won't run into more problems.

just my 2 cents on this.